# How early can I drop off my luggage for EI at DUB to AMS?

Tags: check-in, dublin

At Budapest airport, the check in didn't open until two hours before flight. I wonder whether there's a similar idiocy going on at Dublin or I could drop my luggage off at leisure earlier.

Comment: Can you check in online or on a self service terminal? I have been able to do so well before the regular check-in opened. Not always a help with luggage drop-off but with just hand luggage I could go into the secure zone and relax. (Not Dublin nor Budapest.)

Comment: I am already checked in, that's the easy part these days. I can't drop off a luggage online, alas. Edited to clarify.

Comment: There is a luggage store in the car park across from the terminal, I think it’s £10/day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available on the boarding pass:

[image]

- Europe: Bag Drop for all short-haul flights opens 21⁄2 hours before departure.
- USA Economy: Bag Drop on all long-haul flights opens 3 hours before departure.
- USA Business: Bag Drop available 31⁄2 hours before departure.
- Overnight Check-In is available for short-haul flights departing before 08:00 from Dublin between 16:00 and 20:00 the previous day.

So theoretically the bag drop to Amsterdam opened two and a half hours before departure. In practice, I dropped my bag off some six hours before departure (using the Express automated machine), that was OK. Before security, they scan boarding passes and it flashed red. Security guy checked the computer said I am very early and asked whether I know I can't come out and when I said I know he let me through. And my bag arrived to Amsterdam just fine.